# Different responses in and out of AWS Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using api gateway connected to a Flask Server.

The request itself is a `GET` Request containing this json -

```
{
    "tenantId": "tenant1",
    "customerIds": ["3a315f40-fafd-41a3-8d26-28d8033e053d"]
}
```

I am trying my requests in The Flask itself (Through it's public ip), and it Return 200 with a proper response -

```
{
  "documentsCount": {
    "archive": 0,
    "new": 49,
    "reported": 0
  },
  "tenantId": "005237f9-6779-4c68-89d6-d0800559d4f4"
}
```

When I try to test the request in api gw test zone, it also returns 200

But when I use the api gw's endpoint, it returns - `"Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"`

The return function looks like this -

```
return Trace.MakeResponse(api_name="getStatisticsResponse",
                          trace_id=request.headers.get('Trace-Id'),
                          status="200", message="", request_json=str(request.get_json()),
                          response_json=res)
```

What can I do for this endpoint to return the same responses as the Flask itself?

Comment: how did you create the API GW?  what type of request/response do you have configured?  If this is not configured as a direct passthrough the API GW may be trying to interpret/format the request/response and failing because it's incorrectly configured

Comment: I have configured it as proxy, so all the components should return as is.

Comment: And it is passthrough, I have just checked

Comment: Maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472696/failed-to-decode-json-object-expecting-value-line-1-column-1-char-0-p

Comment: It did! Thank you